# Python: How to escape special __setattr__() in the __init__() method

Tags: python, initialization, setattr

I want to use a Python class that recomputes certain attributes whenever other attributes are changed.

In an older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576009/python-class-property-use-setter-but-evade-getter) (for Python 2) [Martijn Pieters♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) suggested using **setattr** hook , whenever one wants to use a setter without using the getter instead of for example the property decorator.

In my case, this does not work, as I need all variables to be initialized before I can call the special method **setattr**(). However, the **init** method will already call the **setattr** method before all attributes are initialized as you can see in a simplified example below:

```py
class Cuboid():

    def __init__(self, L, W, H):

        self.L = L
        self.W = W
        self.H = H

        # Possibly some more attributes...

        self.V = self.L*self.W*self.H

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):

        super().__setattr__(key, value)

        if key in ['L', 'W', 'H']:

            # Do something if other attributes depende on the variable that is 
            # set e.g.:
            self.V = self.L*self.W*self.H
```

In the first line of the **init** method, the **setattr**() method will be called and it will throw an AttributeError because self.H and self.W are not yet defined.

How do I escape my **setattr** method during initialization of the instance? Or what's another clean, pythonic way to solve this problem?

Comment: Martijn's answer already shows how to bypass `__setattr__`. After all, the `__setattr__` override needs to bypass itself. Look at how that works.

Comment: Thanks, @user2357112. So your suggestion would be to replace

self.L = L

with

super().__setattr__('L', L)

in the __init__() method? Would this be considered good practice?