# How to get setters and getters in python

Tags: python

To use the following:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = None
    @title.setter
    def title(self, title):
        print ('TITLE SETTER: %s' % title)
        self._title = title
```

> NameError: name 'title' is not defined

What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: I ... err ... have you _tried it_ various interpreters?

Comment: this is valid in neither.

Comment: Are you trying to use `@property` ?

Comment: probably you should first create getter using `@property def title(self): return 'Hello World'`. And then you can use `@title`

Comment: @furas that seems like it's the issue.

Comment: as for me it is not issue - if you want to use `@` then you would have to create getter which will create `@title`. If you what `setter` without `getter` then see [Python class @property: use setter but evade getter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576009/python-class-property-use-setter-but-evade-getter)

Comment: @CalebGoodman The user has edited their question multiple times. Previously, Python2 and Python3 featured in the question. You can check the revisions of this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58350677/revisions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name `title` won't exist in the body of the class until you first create it.
The fact is that what allows getters and setters to exist in this way in Python is the descriptor protocol - with a helper callable named `property{ . Back in the old times (circa Python 2.4), it was found out that if property taking a single argument would return a`property`object with a`.setter` attribute, this attribute could be used as a decorator to register the setter method for the same object.

Prior to that one had to declare the getter, setter and deleter as ordinary methods, and create the property object with a line like 
`title = property(title_getter, title_setter, tittle_deleter)` in the class body.

Thus, if you do:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = None

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self._title

    @title.setter
    def title(self, title):
        print 'TITLE SETTER: %s' % title
        self._title = title
```

your code will work, because `property` is called with the 
function `title` as a parameter - it then returns a `property` object,
which have a `__get__` method that will cause that original 
`title` function to be called, and a `setter` and `deleter` attributes,
which are callables - the `title.setter` when used as a decorator,
just add it internally to the property object, so that its `__set__` method
will cause it to be invoked.  (The working of the descriptor protocol and the `__set__`, `__delete__` and `__get__` methods, used internally by `property` is described in the language [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) document)

Comment: is `@property` the same thing as doing `@title.getter`?

Comment: No . The language does not "guess" you will try to create a property with the name "title" - it is declaring the function, and having it decorated with "property" that makes the object "property" with the name "title" exist from that point on.