# Python property setter only

Tags: python

I have a class with property decorator.

```
class Dispatcher:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self._session = None

    @property
    def session(self):
        return self._session

    @session.setter
    def session(self, value):
        self._session = value
```

But I don't need the `getter`, can I have *property* with only the `setter`?

It's most more a curiosity.

Comment: First answer seems useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576009/python-class-property-use-setter-but-evade-getter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python class @property: use setter but evade getter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576009/python-class-property-use-setter-but-evade-getter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way IMHO is

```
class Dispatcher:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self._session = None

    def _set_session(self, value):
        self._session = value

    session = property(fset=_set_session)
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = Dispatcher('a')
>>> d.session = 1
>>> d._session
1
>>> d.session
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#81>", line 1, in <module>
    d.session
AttributeError: unreadable attribute
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make your own "setterOnly"  decorator:

```
# decorator
def setterOnly(f):
    return property(None,f)
```

usage:

```
class P:

    @setterOnly
    def x(self,v): print("setting x to:",v)


p = P()
p.x = 3

setting x to: 3
```

For your class:

```
class Dispatcher:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self._session = None

    @setterOnly
    def session(self,value):
        self._session = value
```