# A technique for a C++-to-Python migrant to lessen the impact of missing identifier declarations

Tags: python, c++

Before coming to a concrete example, let me mention the problem. As a beginning Python programmer with extensive experience in C++, I'm always missing variable declarations. I could yield to the temptation of documenting the type of every nontrivial identifier, but I have a feeling that that would not be terribly pythonic. For one thing, it would be silly that neither the interpreter nor any tool parse these informal declarations. And if the interpreter did, that would be an entirely different language.

As an alternative to writing mere comments, I am contemplating switching to a mode of creating datatypes whose only purpose is to enforce types/interfaces. They would streamline the code and would make me detect type errors at earlier stages. For this convenience I would be paying a little loss in efficiency from the indirection.

For example, to avoid writing as a comment "Dictionary of Employee objects indexed by employeeID", I would write a wrapper class called "EmployeeDict", whose interface would limit the operations that can/cannot be performed.

Would such an idea fly in the long term? Does it defeat the spirit of Python in some way? Is it used by experienced Pythonistas?

For those conversant in C++, I would in other words be translating

```
typedef std::map<EmployeeId, Employee> MyMap;
```

into a type. (Though I am not actually porting any code across.)

**Update**

Even if it's unphythonic, as HumphreyTriscuit confirms, I am loath to write comments that get read by humans without also automating a little the type checking. It's nice that this issue is resolved in 3.5, but I'm stuck for the time being with 2.7, and so I'll mark jsbueno's answer correct until someone can suggest a way—à la "assert isinstance(param, dict)", but one that also concisely confirms the type of the key/value, somewhat paralleling C++—to solve this problem in 2.7.

Comment: Documenting types is definitely not unpythonic, and I would always recommend it. Using someone's API without knowledge of the return types can be a PITA, especially given that Python is strongly typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, as of Python 3.5, the language comes bundled with tools for parameter type annotations that is introspectable by third party tools-  of which tehre might be some ut there already.

Anyway, take a look at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Even if you don't use any other  tools - the way described on PEP 484 above is the "Pythonic way" of declaring types, that won't conflict with other 3rd party tools. So,if you want to write a tool chain of yours as you describe, you should start by creating using function annotations as described on that PEP.

That is good for documenting (and enfocing if the case be), parameters and return values. For class attributes, you can check this answer of mine, based on crafting a special `__setitem__` method on a abse class of your hierarchy:

[Force python class member variable to be specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305751/force-python-class-member-variable-to-be-specific-type/9321953#9321953)

As for local variables - there is no way to enforce/check their type but code comments.

And a last advise to keep you "on the Python way" remember to be permissive and check for interfaces, rather than specific classes.