# How to declare python dataclass member field same as the dataclass type

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

How can I have a member field of a dataclass same as the class name in python3.7+ ?
I am trying to define a class like so (which can be done in Java or C++) -- which might be used as a class for LinkedList node

```
@dataclass
class Node:
  val:str
  next:Node
  prev:Node
```

However, all I get is `NameError: name 'Node' is not defined`. What should be the correct way to have self referential member variables in dataclasses

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305751/how-to-force-ensure-class-attributes-are-a-specific-type) answer your question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add the following import to your file

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

This enables deferred annotations, which are proposed in [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/). Deferred annotations allow you to reference a class that is not yet defined, in your example the `Node` class is not defined when you are still in it's body

Answer (score 9):

Another way is to use a `TypeVar`:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypeVar

Node = TypeVar("Node")

@dataclass
class Node:
  val:  str
  next: Node
  prev: Node
```

This is also useful when dealing with annotations for methods of a class.