# Prohibit class member from being set to None in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way in Python to prohibit class members from being set to None outside of `__init__`?

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self, x):
        if x is not None:
            self.x = x
        else:
            raise Exception("x cannot be None")

d = Dummy("foo")
d.x = None
```

In my code I have type hints, but these are not enforced, so saying `x` can only be `str` does not really change anything in terms of what's allowed.

Comment: You could make `x` a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties), then you can control what happens when someone tries to set it.

Comment: `"I have type hints, but these are not enforced"` as their name suggests, type hints are just, hints

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force/ensure class attributes are a specific type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305751/how-to-force-ensure-class-attributes-are-a-specific-type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        if value is None:
            raise Exception("x cannot be None")
        self._x = value


d = Dummy(8)
d.x = 16
d.x = None  # Raises
```

Comment: Important to point out that (unfortunately) this won't stop someone (if they are truly persistent) from doing `d._x = None`

Comment: In the __init_, it should be self._x

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim No, it's not. Otherwise `Dummy(None)` will work

Comment: @DeepSpace And I suppose there is nothing to prohibit that since Python has no access modifiers?

Comment: @DeepSpace That's true, but in general once you touch underscore-prefixed variables from outside, all guarantees and warranties tend to be invalid :-)

Comment: @MaxPower That's correct. That's part of the "we're all adults" philosophy of Python.

Comment: @MaxPower You can use `__x` for a more mangled name, but no, there's nothing that can stop a truly persistent mis-user.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I have interpreted the question here as meaning preventing *all* attributes from being set to `None` outside of `__init__`, although have added below an option to protect just certain specified attributes.*

How about this?  Have `__setattr__` method as wrapper to `object.__setattr__`.

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._None_forbidden = False
        self.z = None  # this will work
        self._None_forbidden = True

    def __setattr__(self, k, v):
        if v is None and self._None_forbidden:
            raise ValueError("cannot set attribute to None")
        object.__setattr__(self, k, v)


d = Dummy("foo")
print(d.z)  # None
d.y = 2
print(d.y)  # 2
d.x = None  # raises ValueError
```

If you just wanted to protect certain attributes, you could make `self._None_forbidden` into a set of attribute names that are not allowed to be set to None.  For example:

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._None_forbidden = set()
        self.z = None  # this will work
        self._None_forbidden.add("z")

    def __setattr__(self, k, v):
        if v is None and k in self._None_forbidden:
            raise ValueError("cannot set attribute to None")
        object.__setattr__(self, k, v)


d = Dummy("foo")
print(d.z)  # None
d.y = 2
print(d.y)  # 2
d.x = None
print(d.x)  # None
d.z = 4
print(d.z)  # 4
d.z = None  # raises ValueError
```

Obviously if the caller manipulated `_None_forbidden`, then this can be circumvented, but then they should know that they are doing something unsupported.