# TypeError for class instance when checking attributes as suggested by @jusbueno

Tags: python, class, variables

I am referring to the question asked in [How to force/ensure class attributes are a specific type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305751/how-to-force-ensure-class-attributes-are-a-specific-type) (shown bellow).
The type checking works as suggested. However, the class instance has an error. Namely, when instantiate the class as follows and call `__dict__` on it, the error comes up.

excel_parser.py:

```
one_foo = Foo()
one_foo.__dict__
```

results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/fiona/PycharmProjects/data_processing/excel_parser.py", line 80, in <module>
    Foo.__dict__
TypeError: descriptor '__dict__' for 'Foo' objects doesn't apply to a 'Foo' object
```

How can I prevent this from happening? Thx

```
def getter_setter_gen(name, type_):
    def getter(self):
        return getattr(self, "__" + name)
    def setter(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, type_):
            raise TypeError(f"{name} attribute must be set to an instance of {type_}")
        setattr(self, "__" + name, value)
    return property(getter, setter)

def auto_attr_check(cls):
    new_dct = {}
    for key, value in cls.__dict__.items():
        if isinstance(value, type):
            value = getter_setter_gen(key, value)
        new_dct[key] = value
    # Creates a new class, using the modified dictionary as the class dict:
    return type(cls)(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, new_dct)


@auto_attr_check
class Foo(object):
    bar = int
    baz = str
    bam = float
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Please update your question with some more code from `excel_parser.py` from line 80 and before. When I try your code I get no error with: `Foo.__dict__`.